# Limit row where ID, Date, and Code are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL query that gets exam data for employees. There are cases where employees (with the same EMPLID) have a 2nd employment instance, indicated by `EMPL_RCD` and where their data is getting saved to the table for each employment instance. When this occurs I want to limit or select 1 row (instead of 2) where the `EMPLID`, `EXAM_DT`, and `IMMUN_CODE` are the same.

**Sample Data:**

[image]

You can see the two rows highlighted above are duplicated based on those three fields (`EMPLID`, `EXAM_DT`, and `IMMUN_CODE`) In this case I only want to display 1 of them (the row with `EMPL_RCD = 0` if possible).

Here is my query that is producing the above output:

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.EMPL_RCD, COMPANY, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.EXAM_DT,121)) AS EXAM_DT, A.IMMUN_CODE, F.DESCR,  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
  FROM (((PS_GHS_HS_IMMUN A 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  (PS_JOB B INNER JOIN PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY B1 ON (B.EMPLID = B1.EMPLID AND B.EMPL_RCD = B1.EMPL_RCD )) ON  A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID AND B.EMPL_RCD = A.EMPL_RCD ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_LOCATION_TBL E ON  E.LOCATION = B.LOCATION ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_IMMUN_TBL F ON  A.IMMUN_CODE = F.IMMUN_CODE )
  WHERE ( ( B.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB B_ED
        WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ED.EMPLID
          AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ED.EMPL_RCD
          AND B_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))
    AND B.EFFSEQ =
        (SELECT MAX(B_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB B_ES
        WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ES.EMPLID
          AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ES.EMPL_RCD
          AND B.EFFDT = B_ES.EFFDT)
     AND A.EXAM_DT BETWEEN '09-01-2018' AND GETDATE()
     AND E.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_LOCATION_TBL E_ED
        WHERE E.SETID = E_ED.SETID
          AND E.LOCATION = E_ED.LOCATION
          AND E_ED.EFFDT <= B.EFFDT)
     AND F.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_HS_IMMUN_TBL F_ED
        WHERE F.SETID = F_ED.SETID
          AND F.IMMUN_CODE = F_ED.IMMUN_CODE
          AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) ))
  GROUP BY  B.COMPANY,  A.EXAM_DT,  A.IMMUN_CODE,  F.DESCR,  E.DESCR, A.EMPLID, A.EMPL_RCD
  ORDER BY A.EXAM_DT
```

Expected Output is:

[image]

I would like to avoid the use of CTE if possible as I can not use those natively in my query engine.

Comment: update your question and add  youe expected result too

Comment: I added the expected output above

Comment: Why not CTE, you are not using SQL Server 2014?

Comment: You can do it by doing a subquery and using ranking function.

Comment: How would you do it by subquery/ranking method?

Answer (score 0):

seems you need  `MIN(A.EMPL_RCD)`

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, MIN(A.EMPL_RCD), max(B.COMPANY), (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.EXAM_DT,121)) AS EXAM_DT, A.IMMUN_CODE, F.DESCR,  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
  FROM (((PS_GHS_HS_IMMUN A 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  (PS_JOB B INNER JOIN PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY B1 ON (B.EMPLID = B1.EMPLID AND B.EMPL_RCD = B1.EMPL_RCD )) ON  A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID AND B.EMPL_RCD = A.EMPL_RCD ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_LOCATION_TBL E ON  E.LOCATION = B.LOCATION ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_IMMUN_TBL F ON  A.IMMUN_CODE = F.IMMUN_CODE )
  WHERE ( ( B.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB B_ED
        WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ED.EMPLID
          AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ED.EMPL_RCD
          AND B_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))
    AND B.EFFSEQ =
        (SELECT MAX(B_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB B_ES
        WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ES.EMPLID
          AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ES.EMPL_RCD
          AND B.EFFDT = B_ES.EFFDT)
     AND A.EXAM_DT BETWEEN '09-01-2018' AND GETDATE()
     AND E.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_LOCATION_TBL E_ED
        WHERE E.SETID = E_ED.SETID
          AND E.LOCATION = E_ED.LOCATION
          AND E_ED.EFFDT <= B.EFFDT)
     AND F.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_HS_IMMUN_TBL F_ED
        WHERE F.SETID = F_ED.SETID
          AND F.IMMUN_CODE = F_ED.IMMUN_CODE
          AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) ))
  GROUP BY   A.EXAM_DT,  A.IMMUN_CODE,  F.DESCR,  E.DESCR, A.EMPLID
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still yields the above duplicate rows.

Comment: then you have some others value in the rows  hat is not dupicated .. you sample show only a part of the columns you select  .. so in th missing columns there are not duplicated values  ..as  for  A:EMPL_ID ..

Comment: Those are the same 7 columns I have as above. the columns that are duplicated are EMPLID, EXAM_DT, and IMMUN_CODE . TOTAL is also duplicated, however I tested removing that column and am still left with duplicates. Perhaps something I need to change in the GROUP BY ?

Comment: The MIN does not appear to be working as I am getting back rows with 0 and 1 for EMPL_RCD for the same EMPLID, EXAM_DT, and IMMUN_CODE

Comment: If I use that then I am missing out on rows where there is not any duplication, but it is not the MAX(COMPANY).

Comment: in your sample for emplid 5678 you have  company GCL and RPH .. if use group by company you obtain two rows  .. then you could use an aggregation function as max() and remove company from group by the number of rows for this emplid should reduto to one ..